# Error al modificar Excel (xls) con macros usando Apache POI en Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Usando el siguiente código intento agregar datos a un previo xls.
El programa funciona correctamente pero cuando abro el Excel me da el siguiente error:
Hemos encontrado un problema con el contenido....(etc), pero si antes de abrir el archivo la plantilla esta abierta, el documento generado se abre correctamente.

Como puedo hacer para que el xls generado no de error?

Nota: Si uso una hoja de excel sin macros funciona correctamente.
La hoja no esta corrupta.

El código usado para generar el xls:

```
String rutaBase="plantilla.xls";
String rutaArchivoDestino="salida.xls";
    FileInputStream excelFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(rutaBase);
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFileInputStream);
    excelFileInputStream.close();

    //Codigo que modifica datos en las celdas

    File archivox = new File(rutaArchivoDestino);
    if (!archivox.exists()) {
                FileOutputStream excelFileOutPutStream = new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivoXML);
                workbook.write(excelFileOutPutStream);
                excelFileOutPutStream.flush();
                excelFileOutPutStream.close();
               }
```

Comment: Hola. Trata de poner una versión más completa del error, por favor.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.